# What api to call to create token for wailon user

Tags: javascript, php, python, api

I am trying to create a token for login using this api:
[Login API Using Token](https://sdk.wialon.com/wiki/en/sidebar/remoteapi/apiref/token/login)

But i am not able to understand the token cration api for the above.

I see there is a token creation api: [Api for token cration](https://sdk.wialon.com/wiki/en/kit/remoteapi/apiref/token/update) but i am not able to create the token.

Let me know the api call format for Login token creation.

Answer (score 1):

I found answer to this:
You can create the token manually that lasts for 100 days.

using : http://hosting.wialon.com/login.html